# how to make a div take full screen size and stop it from shrinking

Tags: css

I have a  with a className container,

if I do this :

```
.container{
   height:100vh
}
```

whenever I shrink my screen size, for example with dev-tools, the div shrinks as well, how do I stop it from happening? I want it to be full screen always, is that possible?

Comment: (1) *I shrink my screen size for example with dev-tools, the div shrinks as well* == (2) *I want it to be full screen always*

Answer (score 1):

When I understand your question correctly, then the shrinking of the div when resizing the screen is the correct behaviour. `vh` stands for `viewport height`. That means the height stands to the exact relation of the height of your whole screen. If you want the size fixed you have to use `px` or `rem`.

Answer (score 0):

the height being 100vh is the correct answer to have a fullscreen height, perhaps u have other properties in child elements that are causing the div to shrink.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  My fix was to use `vw` instead of `vh`.